# Did Freud adopt an intentionalist ( or representationalist) theory of mind.? ( On Wakefield's reading of Freud's theory of mind)

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, intentionality, freud

- In ***Freud and Philosophy Of Mind***, Jerome Wakefield wants to show that Freud's philosophy of mind is best understood in its Cartesian-Brentanian context.
- According to Brentano, mental acts are essentially (1) intentional ( equated with representational)  and (2) conscious.

Brentano understands the consciousness property as an immediate reflexive intentionality ( analogous to the aristotelian  "I cannot see without seeing that I am in a seeing-state") ; this reflexivity being different from reflexion.

According to Brentano these properties are eidetically necessary, but not logically : there is no a priori absurdity in the idea of an unconscious mental state.

- This opens the door for Freud's theory.
- Freud keeps the intentionality criterion and abandons the consciousness property.

So, according to Freud ( in  Wekefield's reading) mental states are

> (1) brain states
>
> (2) having an intentional / representational content ( Freud is
>   materialist regarding intentionality)
>
> (3) but essentially unconscious ( neither consciously directed towards
>   their objects , nor phenomenbally conscious).
>
> (4) consciousness is an accidental and mysterious quality of some
>   mental states.

My questions : on what textual evidence can one claim that Freud makes of intentionality an / the essential feature of mental states? the author says there are many of them , but does not provide examples.

Comment: Freud is psychology - not philsophy

Comment: Einstein is physics - not philosophy?